# Access session variable in Nginx

Tags: nginx, session-variables

I want to see in Nginx if the current visitor is signed in or not. Is it possible to access session variables (or at least the session ID) in Nginx?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not enough information to answer your question. What programming language, what session system, ...?

You can access the cookies and see if a cookie is present with a certain offset. You won't be able to validate it, but at least you'd have a hint if the user might be logged in or not. No clue if this would meet your requirements.

```
location / {
  if ($http_cookie ~ SESSIONID) {
    // hello there possibly logged in user
  }
}
```